# Is there a way to forward emails associated with a domain without a mail server?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, email, server

A client owns `example1.com` but wants to also purchase `example2.com` and have it point to their original site at `example1.com`. No problem there. But they also want any emails going to `example2.com` to be forwarded to their counter parts at `example1.com`

Eg: if someone emails `info@example2.com` it will be forwarded to `info@example1.com`

They only way I can think of doing this at the moment is to set up host for `example2.com` and then set up mail forwarders in cpanel. But this seems a bit excessive and costly.

Does anyone know another, cheaper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Most mail servers support "virtual alias domains".  This feature allows them to deliver mail from one domain to the accounts at another domain.  It is commonly used for different TLDs owned by the same company (`example.com` and `example.org`) or for misspellings (`example.com` and `exemple.com`).

[According to this thread](http://forums.cpanel.net/f43/set-up-email-aliases-whole-domain-327742.html) you can set this up in cpanel.

> in `cPanel-> Mail-> Forwarders`:
>
> Forward All Email for a Domain
>   In addition to forwarding individual mail accounts, you can forward all email from one domain to another

Comment: To be clear, are you referring to setting up the alias at `example1.com`'s mail server?

Comment: Yes, on the mail server for the domain.

Comment: The question referred to two different domains; the OP didn't want to do it at the second one where there exists no mail server or hosting, and it's not clear from your answer that you're referring to the first domain.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I go about this, when I migrated away from a hosted setup to my private VPS with `Sendmail`

Details: http://mwdesilva.com/posts/howto-setup-mail-forwarding-with-sendmail-in-ubuntu-10-04-lts

The `virtusertable` looks like this,

```
jdoe@virtualdomain.tld     jdoe@gmail.com
```

See my blog post (linked above) for all the details, it's been working great now for well over 3-years.